# Alternative methods to solve DLP for $GL_{3}(\mathbb{F}_2)$

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, alternative-proof

Is there (or rather what is) a more elegant/efficient way to solve the DLP for $g^x=h$ in $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$ where

$$g=\begin{pmatrix}0 &1 & 1 \\ 1 &1 &1 \\ 1&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and

$$h=\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 & 0 \\ 0 &1 &1 \\ 1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
other than using the brute force method which will reveal the answer to be $x=6+7m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $g$ over $\mathbb F_2$ is $p(t) = t^3 + t + 1$ which is irreducible.  The splitting field of this polynomial has $2^3 = 8$ elements, so any nonzero element of it satisfies $r^7 = 1$.  The eigenvalues of $g^7$ are all $1$, and $g^7$ must be diagonalizable over the splitting field since $g$ is, so we must have $g^7 = I$.

Now if
$h = g^k$, an eigenvector of $g$ for eigenvalue $r$ will be an eigenvector of $h$ corresponding for eigenvalue $r^k$.  An eigenvector of $g$ for eigenvalue $r$ is
$$ v = \pmatrix{ r\cr r+1\cr r^2 + r + 1\cr}$$
and
$$ h v = \pmatrix{1 \cr r^2 \cr r^2 + r\cr} = r^{-1} v$$
Thus $h = g^{-1} = g^{6 + 7 m}$ for any $m$.